# Why does PostgreSQL complain about type when I use CASE to SET a field to NULL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have the following query:

```
UPDATE managed_avs 
     SET own_license_expires_at = CASE id WHEN 50 THEN NULL END 
WHERE id in (50)
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "own_license_expires_at" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type text
LINE 1: update managed_avs set own_license_expires_at = CASE id WHEN...
                                                        ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Why does it say that `CASE id WHEN 50 THEN NULL END` is of type text? Isn't it just `NULL`?

Comment: Why do you use the `case` in the first place? The whole statement is equivalent to `update managed_avs 
     SET own_license_expires_at = null where id = 50`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yet it is interesting why this is happening, do you have an explanation?  `timestamp` is nullable in Postgres AFAIK.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This query is generated and is intended for updating multiple rows. I just gave a simplified example here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the case expression returns a `null` value for every possible outcome. As a `null` value has no type, Postgres defaults to `text`.

You can verify that using `pg_typeof()`:

```
select pg_typeof(case id when 50 then null end)
from (values (50) ) as x (id);
```

returns

```
pg_typeof
---------
text
```

In order for this to work either the result of the `when` needs to be cast to a timestamp or the whole expression:

```
case id when 50 then null::timestamp end
```

or

```
(case id when 50 then null end)::timestamp
```

Comment: Thanks! Since my column is of type `timestamp without time zone`, I ended up using `cast(case id when 50 then null end as timestamp without time zone)`.

Comment: I had assumed that `null::timestamp without time zone` wouldn't work because of the spaces in the type name but I just tried it and that works too.